# Chrome extensions can't access localStorage when 3rd party cookies and/or site data is disabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, privacy

A user of me extension recently reported that when he blocked 3rd party cookies, it killed our extension as well. I've traced the issue down to localStorage being inaccessible. I have "storage" and "unlimitedStorage" set in the manifest.json permissions. I am looking into switching to chrome.storage.local, but because it's async, I need to rework a fair bit of code.

Does anyone have an easy workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a workaround while typing this up and tested it:

setting an Cookie Exception of `chrome-exception://* Allow` lets my extension access localStorage.

Not perfect, but it'll do for now.

Comment: Alternately, you can use an extension-specific hostname pattern like `chrome-extension://niaoghengfohplclhbjnjheodgkejpih/` to only allow a certain extension access.